# How to fork a process in node that writes express response

Tags: node.js

I'd like to fork a long running express request in node and send an express response with the child, allowing the parent to serve other requests.  I'm already using cluster but I'd like to fork another process in addition to the cluster for specific long running requests.  What I'd like to prevent is all the processes in the cluster being consumed by a specific long running processes, while most of the other requests are fast.

Thanks

```
var express = require('express');
var webserver = express();

webserver.get("/test", function(request, response) {
    // long running HTTP request
    response.send(...);
});
```

What I'm thinking of is something like following, although I'm not sure this works:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var express = require('express');
var webserver = express();

webserver.get("/test", function(request, response) {
    var child = cp.fork('do_nothing.js');

    child.on("message", function(message) {
        if(message == "start") {
            response.send(...);
            process.exit();
        }
    });

    child.send("start");
});
```

Let me know if anyone knows how to do this.

Edit: So, the idea is that the child could take a long time.  There are a limited number of processes in the cluster serving express responses and I don't want to consume them all on a specific long-running request type.  In the code below, the entire cluster would be consumed by the long running express requests.

```
while(1) {
    if(rand() % 100 == 0) {
        if(fork() == 0) {
            sleep(hour(1));
            exit(0);
        }
    } else {
        sleep(second(1));
    }

    waitpid(WAIT_ANY, &status, WNOHANG);
}
```

Edit: I am going to mark the self-answer as solved.  I'm sure there's a way to pass a socket to a child but it's not really necessary because the cluster master can manage all child processes.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've verified that this is not necessary for my use case, but I was able to get it working using the code below.  It's not exactly what the OP asks for, but it works.

What it's doing is sending an instruction to the cluster master, which forks the additional process upon receipt of the slow express request.

Since the express request doesn't need to know the status of the newly forked cluster worker, it just handles the slow request as normal and then exits.

The instruction to the cluster master informs the master not to replace the dying slow express request process, so the number of workers reverts to the original number after the slow request finishes.

The pool will increase in size when there are slow requests, but revert to normal.  This will prevent like 20 simultaneous slow requests from bringing down the cluster.

```
var numberOfWorkers = 10;
var workerCount = 0;
var slowRequestPids = { };

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++) {
        workerCount++;
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
        workerCount--;

        var pidString = String(worker.process.pid);

        if(pidString in slowRequestPids) {
            delete slowRequestPids[pidString];

            if(workerCount >= numberOfWorkers) {
                logger.info('not forking replacement for slow process');
                return;
            }
        }

        logger.info('forking replacement for a process that died unexpectedly');

        workerCount++;
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on("message", function(msg) {
        if(typeof msg.fork != "undefined" && workerCount < 100) {
            logger.info("forking additional process upon slow request");

            slowRequestPids[msg.fork] = 1;

            workerCount++;
            cluster.fork();
        }   
    });

    return;
}

webserver.use("/slow", function(req, res) {
    process.send({fork: String(process.pid) });

    sleep.sleep(300);

    res.send({ response_from: "virtual child" });

    res.on("finish", function() {
        logger.info('process exits, restoring cluster to original size');

        process.exit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code block is confusing because it appears that you're killing the parent process with `process.exit()` rather than the child.

In any case, if we assume the problem is this:

1. You have a cluster of "regular processes".
2. Occasionally, you want to take an incoming request that was assigned to one of the cluster processes and pass it off to a long running child that will eventually send the response.
3. After sending the response, the long running child process should exit.

You have a couple options.

1. You can have the clustered process that was assigned the request, start up a child, send it some initial data and listen for a message back from the child.  When it gets the message back from the child, it can send the response and kill the child. This appears to be what you're attempting to do in your second code block.
2. You can have the clustered process that was assigned the request, start up a child and reassign the request socket to the child process and the child can then own that socket from then on.  When it finally sends the response, it can then exit itself.

The first is simpler because no socket assignment from one process to another is required.  To implement the second, you'd have to write or find the code to do socket reassignment and then reconstituted as an express request within the child.  The cluster module does something like this so the code is there to be found and learned from, but I'm not aware of a trivial way to do it.

Personally, I don't see any particular downside to the first.  I suppose if the clustered process were to die for some , you'd lose the long running request socket, but hopefully you can just code your clustered processes not to die unnecessarily.

---

You can read this article on sending a socket to a new node.js process:

[Sending a socket to a forked process](https://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1930)

And, this node.js doc on sending a socket:

[Example: sending a socket object](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object)

Comment: thank you.  I'm not sure the first option is what I want, because I want the parent to immediately return to handle other requests.  If the parent is listening for a message back from the child, would it be able to serve other requests? for the sake of argument, assume there is no cluster and the parent is the only process.  Would all other requests block until the parent gets a message from the child? perhaps I'm missing something.  Thanks for your response, I'll look at option two if option one is not possible

Comment: @AbdulAhad - A parent listening for a child message can do zillions of other things.  That's just an event listener, doing absolutely nothing until the moment the message arrives and even then it's probably only a few ms to process the message.  Because of the asynchronous architecture a single node.js process can work on thousands of requests.

Comment: ok. well, the process is dedicated to processes express requests.  Say for example that the child has to send a 10GB response, it could take some time.  I want the parent to be able to handle additional express requests.  the child would be doing all the work in the send() method, I just want the parent to start processing other requests immediately

Comment: @AbdulAhad - OK, so what's the question then?  That would be option 2 to reassign the request socket to the dedicated child.  FYI, you seem to be unaware of the ability of node.js to serve LOTS of requests from one process.  Just sending 10GB of data does not preclude that process from doing lots of other things.  Most of the time you are sending 10GB of data, you are waiting for TCP flow control and an acknowledgement from the other end of packets delivery confirmation and there should be tons of CPU available for other request processing.  node.js uses non-blocking networking.

Comment: @AbdulAhad - It sounds to me like you are jumping the gun in assuming you need lots of processes before you've even implemented the simplest solutions and tested what you have.  Expand to more processes ONLY when you've proven you actually need it.

Comment: ok, you're right, I'm going to try to verify it's necessary.  I'll update the question to give you an idea of what I'm thinking

Comment: @AbdulAhad - At this point, I think I've answered the question you originally asked and you can probably accept this answer.  If you run into more questions related to how you're scaling your solution, you should probably ask a new question.   Stack overflow does not want you to keep adding more details and questions to your original question.  Ask quesetion, get answer to what was originally asked.  If more questions arise, ask new question.  I'm happy to continue to help, but probably in follow-on questions, not by continuing a discussion of other topics here.

Comment: ok, yeah, I'm going to try to reassign the socket as you originally said.  thanks again. I'm certain the entire cluster will be consumed if the parent doesn't return to serve new express requests.  I think your second suggestion solves it.  I'm going to leave it open for a while in the case that someone has already implemented this. it's probably 2 or 3 lines of code that's already been written

Comment: @AbdulAhad - Two references added to the end of my answer on sending a socket to another process in node.js.

Comment: yeah, I'm sure there's a way to do it. I'm just going to mark the self-answer as solved when the option is available.  thanks